# Manipulate Evaluation Order Problem

Tags: evaluation, manipulate

I seem to be getting some unintended results from a nested `Manipulate` that I have not been able to resolve.  I boiled down the problem I'm having to a simplified version.
I can not seem to get the evaluation order of `Manipulate` correct.

```
Manipulate[
 Manipulate[
  Print[{Parity, n}];
  {Parity, n},
  {n, Select[Range[1, 10, 1], Parity]}
 ],
 {Parity, {OddQ, EvenQ}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem isn't what it shows in the window, it is with what the Print statement outputs. For instance, if it is in the state EvenQ,2 and I click on OddQ, the Print output will read:

```
{OddQ,2}
```

Despite the fact that it shows {OddQ,1} in the window.

Why is this, and how can I fix it? In this boiled-down example it doesn't matter, but in my real life one, an error is issued every time I switch the outer manipulate.

Comment: This is weird indeed. Change, for instance, the line `{Parity, n}` to `a={Parity, b=n}` and evaluate a `Dynamic[{a,b}]` in a new cell and see what happens then if you press the parity buttons. The value of a and b do not correspond to the displayed value of n in the Manipulate box even though they are the results of an assignment using the same n.

Comment: If I add the option `TrackedSymbols :> {n}` to the inner manipulate, the _incorrect_ print output disappears and the window displays correct at all times. This _solution_ prevents the error I was getting in the un-boiled-down problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't help you with why your code doesn't work, but this seems to work. In this solution `n` is reset to either 1 or 2 when `Parity` is changed before `Print` is called.

```
Manipulate[Manipulate[
  If[Not[Parity[n]], n = Mod[n + 1, 2, 1]];
  Print[{Parity, n}];
  {Parity, n},
  {n, Select[Range[1, 10, 1], Parity]}], {Parity, {OddQ, EvenQ}}]
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you should be nesting `Manipulate` objects.  The fact that you are dealing with Dynamic objects means that things often don't work quite as they do otherwise.

See: [Why won't this work? Dynamic in a Select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1179430/618728)

Here is an example of a scoping irregularity that is easily produced with `Block` and `Manipulate`:

```
Parity = "You shouldn't see this.";

Block[{Parity = EvenQ},
 Manipulate[
  {Parity, n},
  {n, Select[Range@10, Parity]}
 ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I recommend that you use `Manipulate` only in simple cases, turning to manual construction with `DynamicModule`, `Control`, etc. when you need something complicated.