# ControlType -> None Vs. Module inside Manipulate (i.e. making everything local)

Tags: programming, manipulate, scoping, core-language

I'm building a program on another one made available in the Wolfram Demonstration Project.

I've noticed that in the original code (working flawlessly) many variables were made local inside the *Manipulate* wrapper by making *ghost* controls, i.e.

```
{var1, ControlType -> None}
{var2, ControlType -> None}
{var3, ControlType -> None}...
```

and there was no *Module* instruction inside the Manipulate.

I also found out that, after some changes made by me, the code wasn't anymore behaving well and that the main body of the manipulate command was executed two times after changing a control value.

By trial and error I managed to fix that double execution by inserting a *Module* command encapsulating a new variable created by me (causing the problem), that was global and that re-triggered the evaluation of the *Manipulate* body section.

I've read elsewhere that making all variables local inside a *Manipulate* can be a good programming practice and that guideline actually helped me to pinpoint the problem and avoid the *double evaluation* issue.

The whole code is too complex and long to be posted here and also to be reduced to a stripped down example.

So **my questions** are rather theoretical but probably clear enough in their essence to be answered by some *Mathematica* user more expert than me.

They are:

1) What's the difference (if any) between using a *Module* or using the *ControlType -> None* technique?

2) I've some compiled functions inside the *Initialization* section of the *Manipulate*. I see that those compiled functions are *global* and I don't know how to make them *local*. Do I have to leave them *global* without worrying much (there's no apparent issue about them till now) or is it advisable to make them *local* somehow (if so, how)?

Comment: `Manipulate` is user friendly version of `DynamicModule`. `DM` variables are owned by `FrontEnd` while `Module's` by `Kernel`. This difference may be used for your benefit but also may be causing problems if you are not careful. I strongly recommend `Advanced Dynamic Functionality` tutorial to go through. Ad 2) `DynamicModule` is the way to go.

Comment: @Kuba I find your comment, although brief, to be enlightening.  You may wish to convert it to an Answer and add a link to `Advanced Dynamic Functionality` to make it more accessible to readers.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Here's the link [AdvancedDynamicFunctionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html). I will hold on with answer now, maybe I can find related topics or duplicates.

Comment: It could be added to [Question 559](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs) too.  And, thanks for the link.

Comment: If you make the variables local to a Module inside Manipulate expression, then their values are no longer saved between refreshes of the expression. So you can't use them to store counters and other values that you want to remain saved as the simulation is running. Basically a new clean copy of these variables are made each time the expression is refreshed. So, rule of thumb: If you want to save the value of something between refreshes, you need to use `{{x,0},None}`. For (2), you should not make variables in Initializations. Only function definitions. Variables there become global.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for the refresh heads up. That's an interesting point to consider and that probably answers my 1) question about the differences in using a Module or ghost controls in a practical way. You could make it an answer, probably useful for others. For (2) all the variables used in the compiled functions defined in the initialization are local (Module-ed inside the function definition). I meant to say that the compiled functions themselves (the function names) are global.

Comment: @kuba thanks for your advice and for the information about the FrontEnd and Kernel ownership of variables. I know about Advanced Dynamic Functionality but I don't think I'm up to translating a complex pre-made manipulate code structure into it at the moment.

Comment: There is some discussion of this in the Q&A [17112](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17112/what-does-none-mean-in-a-control-specification-for-manipulate).

Comment: For 2), I usually use `Manipulate[Plot[f[x],{x,0,1}],{{f,f},None},Initialization:>(f[x_]:=x^2)]`. The `{f,f}` is prevents `f` from being set equal to `0` before `Initialization` is executed.

Comment: The others have summarised #1. local variables are stored in the notebook. If you use Module there is a strong chance you will see pink boxes next time you open the notebook (until you re-evaluate). #2 you do not necessarily need to localise functions. Personally I *never* do. Read the docs for `Initialization` and `SynchronousInitialization` and study the examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My feeling is that this question is probably too broad and a definitive answer might be too long or nearly impossible.  This a comment to point out issues to consider in deciding whether and how to localize symbols.

**+** 
Is the application self-contained?  Or does it consist of several components that need access to a shared variable (e.g. a database or common utility functions)?  Is the notebook going to consist of several independent `Manipulate` programs whose variables and functions need to be isolated from each other?  Could other notebooks opened by the user interfere with your program?

**+** 
Localizing by nesting modules and dynamic modules (including `Manipulate` which constructs a `DynamicModule`) can have advantages and disadvantages.  When they are nested with `Dynamic` as well, things can get complicated to explain.  Most, if not all, of these are discussed in other questions.  See the references below for some of them.  It is perhaps worth repeating here that code of the forms

```
Module[{x}, Manipulate[prog[x],...]]
Block[{x}, Manipulate[prog[x],...]]
```

is asking for trouble.  Note that as of V10, the `x` is highlighted in red as a warning.

**+** 
Some find the automatic handling of controls and formatting by `Manipulate` irritating to control and recommend doing it all by hand with `DynamicModule`.  Sometimes one is unaware of exactly what `Manipulate` is doing, and in complicated `Dynamic` situations, the lack of awareness can lead to bugs.

**+** 
Similarly `SaveDefinitions`, another automatic handler, can cause unanticipated problems.

**+** 
It's important to understand what happens in your application when the notebook is first opened by the end user.

**+** 
In short, there are situations where one needs the variables and functions localized and situations where one needs them not localized. For myself, my inclination is to keep the nesting of the `DynamicModules` to a minimum and put all the variables in the `Manipulate` or outer `DynamicModule`, when possible.  There are usually fewer problems.  For intermediate results, I use nested `Withs`, which has the advantage of not creating a tracked symbol.

**References**

Relevant discussion of the issues:
[What does None mean in a control specification for Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17112/what-does-none-mean-in-a-control-specification-for-manipulate/17113#17113),
[Unexpected Setter Bar Behavior when Manipulate Nested in Dynamic Module](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29459/unexpected-setter-bar-behavior-when-manipulate-nested-in-dynamic-module/29510#29510) (note the comments, too)

The issues go back a ways:
[Manipulate Evaluation Order Problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3323/manipulate-evaluation-order-problem),
[Question about scoping data in a multi-level Manipulate construction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/question-about-scoping-data-in-a-multi-level-manipulate-construction)

And they persist:
[Manipulate in Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64025/manipulate-in-manipulate)

`Initialization` and `SaveDefinitions` issues:
[DynamicModule, SaveDefinitions and global functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39631/dynamicmodule-savedefinitions-and-global-functions),
[Working with DynamicModule: Tracking the progress of Initialization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59949/tracking-initialization)

And there are more....