# How to use locally scoped dynamic variables in Manipulate for expression and control parameters

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, variable-definitions, scoping

I have a `Manipulate` that has dynamic variables that I want to use in the displayed expression and use in the parameters for the manipulate controls.  I only calculate these dynamic variables when one of the `TrackedSymbols` changes using `Refresh`.  It all works. However, these variables are in scope outside of the `Manipulate`.  I would like them not to be as they are only needed inside of it.

The variables whose scope I want to restrict are `lower` and `upper`.  After I execute this they are available in the notebook to query and alter. How do I restrict their scope?  The two function definitions are included below as well.

```
Manipulate[

 Refresh[
  lower = distPlotRange[distribution, -1, 4];
  upper = distPlotRange[distribution, 1, 4];
  fillRange = {Max[#[[1]]], Min[#[[2]]]} &[Transpose[{fillRange, {lower, upper}}]];
  ,
  TrackedSymbols :> {distribution}
  ];

 plotPdfInterval[distribution, Interval[fillRange],
  PlotRange -> {{lower, upper}, {0, Full}},
  PlotStyle -> Orange,
  Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Blue,
  AxesOrigin -> {lower, 0}]
 ,
 {fillRange, Dynamic@lower, Dynamic@upper, IntervalSlider, Method -> "Push", MinIntervalSize -> 0.01},
 {{distribution, NormalDistribution[]}, 
   {NormalDistribution[], StudentTDistribution[15], LogNormalDistribution[5, 1]}, 
   PopupMenu},
 Initialization :> (fillRange = {-1, 1};)]
```

First some utility functions:

```
plotPdfInterval[dist_?DistributionParameterQ, interval_, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] :=
 Module[{distPdf = PDF[dist, #] &},
   Plot[distPdf[x], {x, Min[interval], Max[interval]}, opts]
  ]

distPlotRange[dist_?DistributionParameterQ, boundary_?(MemberQ[{-1, 1}, #] &), stdDevs_?NumberQ] :=
 With[{qt = Quantile[dist, If[boundary == -1, 0, 1]]},
  If[NumberQ@qt, qt, 
   Mean@dist + boundary stdDevs StandardDeviation@dist]]
```

Comment: @Karsten7. Adding them to the controls section works.  However, the defaults do not work there so I have to use `{lower, None}` and keep the `Initialization` option.  May you add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: [ControlType -> None Vs. Module inside Manipulate (i.e. making everything local)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72422/18476) might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can localize the scope of variables to `Manipulate` by adding them as arguments to `Manipulate` with [`ControlType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ControlType.html) `None`. For your case

```
Manipulate[Refresh[lower = distPlotRange[distribution, -1, 4];
  upper = distPlotRange[distribution, 1, 4];
  fillRange = {Max[#[[1]]], Min[#[[2]]]} &[
    Transpose[{fillRange, {lower, upper}}]];, 
  TrackedSymbols :> {distribution}];
 plotPdfInterval[distribution, Interval[fillRange], 
  PlotRange -> {{lower, upper}, {0, Full}}, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
  Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Blue, 
  AxesOrigin -> {lower, 0}], {fillRange, Dynamic@lower, Dynamic@upper,
   IntervalSlider, Method -> "Push", 
  MinIntervalSize -> 0.01}, {{distribution, 
   NormalDistribution[]}, {NormalDistribution[], 
   StudentTDistribution[15], LogNormalDistribution[5, 1]}, 
  PopupMenu}, {lower, None}, {upper, None},
 Initialization :> (fillRange = {-1, 1};)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can insert your `Manipulate[...]` in a `DynamicModule[{lower,upper},...]`:

```
DynamicModule[{lower, upper},
 Manipulate[
  Refresh[
   lower = distPlotRange[distribution, -1, 4];
   upper = distPlotRange[distribution, 1, 4];
   fillRange = {Max[#[[1]]], Min[#[[2]]]} &[
     Transpose[{fillRange, {lower, upper}}]];,
   TrackedSymbols :> {distribution}
   ];
  plotPdfInterval[distribution, Interval[fillRange], 
   PlotRange -> {{lower, upper}, {0, Full}}, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
   Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Blue, 
   AxesOrigin -> {lower, 0}], {fillRange, Dynamic@lower, 
   Dynamic@upper, IntervalSlider, Method -> "Push", 
   MinIntervalSize -> 0.01}, {{distribution, 
    NormalDistribution[]}, {NormalDistribution[], 
    StudentTDistribution[15], LogNormalDistribution[5, 1]}, 
   PopupMenu}, Initialization :> (fillRange = {-1, 1};)]
 ]
```

`DynamicModule[{lower,upper},...]` saves the variables `lower` and `upper` when the notebook is closed. You don't need that. I don't think that is a problem, but if it is, add the option `UnsavedVariables -> {lower,upper}`.